# Wifi Only Works After Suspending MacBook Pro (7,1) with 16.04

Tags: wireless, 16.04, broadcom, macbook-pro

[This is apparently an issue](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2314494), but has yet to get any concrete solutions to resolve it.

I was hoping someone is able to help debug this.

The WiFi will work just fine after awaking from suspend, but not on inital startup.  I have to login, close laptop or suspend, then open laptop or awaken from suspend in order to get functional WiFi. Makes me wonder if something happened to init between 14.04 and 16.04 as this was not an issue for me in the past.

Any help at all would be appreciated as the forums are hush thus far.

Kernel: 4.4.0-22-generic

Wireless Adapter: Broadcom BCM4322 802.11 a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)

Answer (score 0):

After a fresh boot, try running these commands and see if the WiFi comes alive:

```
sudo su
service network-manager stop
ifconfig wlp2s0 down
ifconfig wlp2s0 up
service network-manager start
exit
```

Comment: `# service network-manager stop  `  

`# ifconfig wlan0 down`  Output is `wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device  `
`# ifconfig wlan0 up` Output is  `wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device  `
`# service network-manager start  `

Comment: @Ski - please post the output of `ifconfig`.

Comment: `# ifconfig wlan0 down` got me this: `wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device`  And inputing `# ifconfig wlan0 up` got me this: `wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device`

Comment: @Ski - That's not what I asked for. I asked for the output of `ifconfig`

Comment: Sorry.  `$ ifconfig` gives me three categories of output.  One is `enp3s0`, another is `lo` and the last is `wlp2s0`.  The details of `wlp2s0` are `Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f8:1e:df:f2:44:f1  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:147
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:21`

Comment: I've edited the commands. Please try them again.

Comment: Replacing `wlan0` with `wlp2s0` does not seem to bring about a functioning WiFi either.  There continues to be zero networks displayed until I suspend / close-laptop and then awaken / open-laptop.

Comment: Swapped in `wlp2s0` for `wlan0` doesn't seem to resolve the issue.